# How do I move my current active window from one monitor to another using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors

I use a multiple-monitor setup on Windows XP. I would like to be able to move the active window from one monitor to the other with a keyboard shortcut.

I know that I can use `Alt+Space, M`, or drag the window with the mouse. But is it possible to do this with a single keyboard shortcut?

Comment: OK, I need freeware/opensource tool.

Comment: This Q is about WinXP, so just for people interested in Win7: WIN+Right/Left Cursor will rotate the current window from current to docked at side of current window, docked at near side of next window, normal in next window, .... eventually (depending on monitor count) to where it started.

Comment: @Richard: In Win7 you can _move_ the active window from one screen to the other with WIN+Shift+Right/Left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) can do this.

[image]

Comment: Hm... the problem is, that in the license agreement there is written: "Noncommercial: You may not use this work for commercial purposes."

Comment: @ViliusK Winsplit revolution FAQ says the following:
The actual licence's "non-commercial" term just means that you can't directly make benefits with WinSplit Revolution.
For example, you can't include it in a commercial package of software that you would sell.
But as it is a freeware, you can distibute it freely as often as you want. [link](http://winsplit-revolution.com/faq)

Comment: Link not longer works

Comment: I really like winsplit, because it gives you the ability to put/size windows on 1/3, 1/2, or 2/3 of the screen (or in the corner of the screen).  It's a shame the web site was shut down.

Answer (score 108):

In Windows 7 you can instantly move the active window from one monitor screen to another with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>.

Comment: The question was for Windows XP, not Windows 7.

Comment: It's one of the top hits on a google search.  Fantastic!

Comment: Works in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks! Life saver :) Full screen game crashed so I had a black screen on my main monitor and anything I opened (like task manager to end the task) opened behind that.

Comment: this does not work with radmin viewer

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Multimon Taskbar](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm). They have a free version. You can use Ctrl-Alt-left/right to move the window between the monitors.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). It provides that feature and many more.

From the linked page:

> UltraMon is a utility for multi-monitor systems, designed to increase productivity and unlock the full potential of multiple monitors.
>
> - efficiently move windows and maximize windows across the desktop
> - manage more applications with the Smart Taskbar
> - control application positioning with UltraMon Shortcuts
> - multi-monitor support for desktop wallpapers and screen savers
> - mirror your main monitor to secondary monitors for a presentation

Comment: OK, I need freeware/opensource tool.

Comment: Ultramon is fantastic, I can't recommend it strongly enough. Well worth the money IMO. (No, I'm not affiliated :P)

Comment: It also integrates well with Taskbar Shuffle, which is very important to have on any Windows pre-7. It lets you rearrange the taskbar via drag and drop.

Answer (score 2):

[MurGeeMon](http://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/) is paid software that can move windows with keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) is my choice because it can hook to Ctrl+` and works in Windows 8.

[image]

Comment: Something got mixed up, this tool on the screenshot is called "Swap Screen" and is part of [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/swapscreen.html)

Answer (score 1):

I like [ZBar](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/zbar/) because it's free and good enough for my purposes. You can move a window between monitors with Ctrl+Alt+Arrow.  It also gives you a second taskbar which looks more native than Multimon Taskbar (but not as good as Ultramon).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

1. Select the Window with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. And then repeatedly press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For those reading it in 2021 and later, and using Windows 10, please try:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>⬅</kbd> to move to the monitor on the left side (or split the screen
in half and snap to the left side)

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>➡</kbd> - as above, but right side

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>⬆</kbd> - maximize/restore

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>⬇</kbd> - minimize/restore

For more hotkeys see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec