# Preview second screen in main one

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have an installation with 4 tv's connected to an a HDMI hub and this hub is connected as second display in a windows 10 computer.

All is working nice, but all tv's are far away from the computer, so when we expand the desktop to play some video (VLC, youtube etc...) we have to fish with the mouse to find the opened window to bring it back to main desktop and change what is being played.

Actually we make a workaround turning off desktop expansion and changing video, but I was guessing:

There is some way to preview **in the main screen** what is being displayed in second one?

Comment: With VLC, you should be able to open another window and use it as a remote control/preview. I do not know exactly how (and I'm not even sure about it), that's why I'm writing a comment and not an answer. I think it's in an "Interface" or "Window" menu or something like that.

Comment: @NathanShiraini this won't really solve problem, I need to know where the windows are placed to move them, maximizing in second screen is not a problem but yes operate with apps / windows opened there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multi-monitor management software is very helpful for situations it sound like you are in, however to accomplish the specific goal of accessing windows on other desktops you mention it is easily done with hotkeys in Windows.

Use `Alt-Tab` until the window you'd like to move is selected, then press `Windows-Left_arrow` or `Windows-Right_arrow` to move the window between screens (these hotkeys are used alongside `Windows-Up_arrow`(maximize) and `Windows-Down_arrow` (minimize) for window management out of the box).

For previewing the contents of other screens, using something like [Open Broadcaster](https://obsproject.com/) is an option that not only gives you a preview of specific screens, windows, and select screen regions all on a customizable layout; it also allows you to record and even live-stream the contents of those regions with a lot of different control. The best part is that this software is free.

Comment: OBS is your best bet, OP.

Comment: After reading a bunch of suggestions on other sites (like some driver feature that only works with ATO cards, an extension for UltraMon, and the paid 'Remote Monitor' app suggested in one of the answers), I'm glad I finally came across this one. I've never used OBS because I have no real interest in actually recording or streaming my screen, but it works perfectly for this, and the recording and streaming features can easily be hidden.

Comment: Specifically on how to do this in OBS Studio: Create a scene and call it e.g. "Second screen". Add a Display Capture source pointing at the screen you want to view. Then right click on the source and say 'fit to screen'.  Right click on the Scene and say 'Windowed Projector'. You'll get a preview window showing you your other screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app in Microsoft Store: [Remote Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NN0KDBW0550), it does what you want. It's very easy to use. You can see the second display inside a window in your primary monitor and use the mouse normally in both monitors. You will see the pointer at any time and be able to control everything. You can even see a "map" overlayed with the position of the monitors and the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to fish with the mouse, just right-click on the taskbar and choose "Cascade windows" this will cascade all opened windows on your screen including any opened window in any monitor.

The second option you have is a third-party tool. You can use a multi-monitor management tool like [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/). This will give you some useful and helpful features that can saves a lot of time and effort. One of the features is bringing any window or app from any monitor to any monitor you want with a customized HotKey. So, this could be a solution to your problem. However, the free version of DisplayFusion has limited functions (including this function), but the pro version has them all and you can use it for 30-days trail or buy it for about $25 for a life-term license.

Third Option is via this link : 
[How do I move my current active window from one monitor to another using a keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/234627/how-do-i-move-my-current-active-window-from-one-monitor-to-another-using-a-keybo)

Comment: using third party soft is not a problem, even paying license, I've installed DisplayFusion and does not fit my needs, also *One of the features is bringing any window or app from any monitor to any monitor you want with a customized HotKey* I can use own windows shortcuts.

Comment: DisplayFusion has a "Mirror Monitor" function, which can be triggered through an assigned keyboard shortcut and shall produce a "live view" of all the monitors that are available to the Windows OS. Though, it is a true "mirror" as nothing interaction can take place over the mirrored window.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on the previous answer yet so I joined just to say the Remote Monitor app is **exactly** what I have been looking for. The app is very simple, straight-forward, and doesn't consume much resources. I had found a Mac alternative in the past called [Jibapps Displays](https://www.jibapps.com/apps/displays/) but couldn't find a windows equivalent until now. Only minor con is that they're both $4.99 but it's well worth it.

This is useful when a presenting computer needs to be in a different location than the projector/external display and you need to use your primary display for other tasks. For me, I am using this in a church setting to present material to a live audience and also broadcasting over WebEx. So, a clean view for the audience is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use "**Print Screen**" on your computer.
It will copy all your extended display including your main display onto your clipboard. Paste your clipboard onto your main display e.g. Powerpoint application to preview all your display within your main display.
This only allows you to preview what is being displayed on other display quickly, not allowing you to see real-time videos of other displays on your main display.