# Preview one monitor in a window

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Is there a program for Windows 10 which will give a preview of the output to a monitor in a window?

The use case is for a presentation context, I'd like to mirror the projector onto the stage display monitor (a separate monitor from the primary monitor), whilst also showing additional information on the stage display.

Comment: Why don't you just move the stuff you want to show on the stage display to that display?

Comment: @cascer1 because I want to show it on multiple displays at once. Cloning isn't an option because the screens are different resolutions, and I want to show additional content on the stage display.

Comment: See my answer here, specifically the bottom paragraph: http://superuser.com/questions/1099363/preview-second-screen-in-main-one/1102345#1102345

Comment: @JaredT Sounds like pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.