# Dual Monitors (Landscape and Portrait) - Resize Application Window automatically

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, landscape, portrait

I have a dual monitors setup so that one monitor is in landscape mode, the other is in portrait. And being programmer, I love the setup. Screen resolutions and all work fine, *except one caveat*.

When I drag and drop application window (for example, Google Chrome) from landscape to portrait mode, the window goes outside the portrait mode. It is quite irritating to resize the window every time. I understand that I can maximize the window. But I prefer not to do that.

Is there a way, so that the window will be automatically resized to the size of width of the other screen?

Here is the animated gif that can describe the issue. Thank you for all your help/comments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging the window by mouse, use [the shortcut for that purpose: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd>](https://superuser.com/a/394861/241386). It'll move the window to the previous/next display and resize it relatively to the destination screen

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for. However, what I noticed is that for Chrome/IE/Word and may other applications do not keep their original size when I click (win + shift + Left twice).  Hope you know what I am saying.

Comment: yes, probably it only resizes the windows when they're larger than the destination display

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried Windows 10's auto snap feature? Drag the title bar until the mouse about to hit the edge of the screen, especially top screen edge.

or you can also try the classic combo <kbd>Win key</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>.

<kbd>Win key</kbd>+<kbd>up  arrow</kbd> will maximize the current window

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this. But I do not want to maximize window.

Comment: hmm. i just answered that. and you mark me down. strange. 
win key + arrow combo is the oldest trick since win 7.

i have not found any third party app that auto resize the window border when approaching the screen edge. windowfx from stardock does monitor screen edge. but only to prevent the window to go over the edge. it cannot resize it when reaching  screen edge. also, some type of window forms  did not support resize

Comment: the OP already stated in the original question: "I understand that I can maximize the window. But I prefer not to do that". The fact that you didn't found any software to do that doesn't mean they don't exist. You can always write your own, or just use an AHK script

Comment: please notice, the other answer has the same answer as me. 
rather than using "win key + arrow", he is using image. 
yes, shift + win key + arrow has also add different function. 
but basicly, win key + arrow combo.
I'm not complaining here. 
I just clarifying the question 
and provide some hint of existing third party software.
Stardock's window fx. 
Although not automaticly resize the border, but it has many function for multiple screen workspace. 

Lets just focus on answer. I just tried to help. not to complicate things.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am very well aware of edge snapping. (it is been there from Windows 7, called Aero Snap). Notice if you use Win + Right Arrow combination, it will dock the window on right side and shrink it in half. If you use a secondary monitor in portrait mode (as shown above), it will right-align the window and shrink it in half. This will be nearly unusable. @phuclv's answer is more what I have been asking. Thank you.